# Is it possible to alter a table generated from JSON data by adding in manual data?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am building this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ3oD.png) through json data fed in from a php script.

**I want to go back and add in the total number of students per *unique* location**. So for example, the row after “EOF/TRiO” will total the number of students for that location – which is 2. And the final row of “Learning Center” (before ‘Student Success Office’) will read Total - 71 students.
Is this possible to do so?

This is how I am building my table (ajax):

```
function getTablularStats(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
  var tabular = resp.msg.tabular_num_meetings;
  var cohort = resp.msg.cohort;

  var html = "";
  html += `<h5>Category: ${cohort}</h5>`;
  html += "<table class='table small table-responsible-sm table hover table-sm table-stripped'>";
  html += `<tr><th>Location</th><th>Meetings</th><th>Number of Students</th></tr>`;

  for(let key in tabular) {
    let obj = tabular[key]
    for(let innerKey in obj) {
      html += `<tr>`;
      html += `<td><b>${key}</b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b>${innerKey}</b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b>${obj[innerKey]}</b></td>`;
      html += `</tr>`;
    }
  };
  html += "</table>";
  return html;
}
```

JSON format:

```
"msg": {
    "num_meetings": {
      "EOF/TRiO": {
        "4 Meetings": 1,
        "11 Meetings": 1
      },
      "Learning Center": {
        "1 Meetings": 8,
        "2 Meetings": 10,
        "3 Meetings": 4,
        "4 Meetings": 9,
        "5 Meetings": 2,
        "6 Meetings": 1,
        "7 Meetings": 2,
        "8 Meetings": 1,
        "13 Meetings": 1
      },
      "Student Success Coach Office": {
        "3 Meetings": 2,
        "4 Meetings": 1
      }
    }
  }
```

Backend:

```
  ...
  $stmt->execute();
  $q_result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


  $tabular = array();
  foreach($q_result as $r) {
    $location = $r['location'];
    $apptCount = $r['appointments'];
    $tabular[$location][$apptCount . " Meetings"] += 1;
  }

  echo json_encode(array(
    'success' => 1,
    'msg' => array(
      'cohort' => $cohort_type,
      'attendance_per_week' => $attendance_per_week,
      'num_meetings' => $occurence,
      'tabular_num_meetings' => $tabular
    )
  ));
}
```

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the below code can solve your problem. For each key you can calculate the total numbers of students while computing the html code. And after you calculated all the inner keys then you can add the row that shows total numbers. I didn't have time to test it. But it should do the job.

```
function getTablularStats(resp) {
  console.log(resp);
  var tabular = resp.msg.tabular_num_meetings;
  var cohort = resp.msg.cohort;

  var html = "";
  html += `<h5>Category: ${cohort}</h5>`;
  html += "<table class='table small table-responsible-sm table hover table-sm table-stripped'>";
  html += `<tr><th>Location</th><th>Meetings</th><th>Number of Students</th></tr>`;

  for(let key in tabular) {
    let obj = tabular[key]
    let total = 0; // for each key you can calculate
    for(let innerKey in obj) {
      html += `<tr>`;
      html += `<td><b>${key}</b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b>${innerKey}</b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b>${obj[innerKey]}</b></td>`;
      html += `</tr>`;
      total+=obj[innerKey];//in every inner key update the total
    }
    //after you generated all rows relevant to the key
    //then you can add total row here
      html += `<tr>`;
      html += `<td><b>total for ${key}</b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b></b></td>`;
      html += `<td><b>${total}</b></td>`;
      html += `</tr>`;
  };
  html += "</table>";
  return html;
}
```

Comment: I think he wants the sum for each unique sections, not for the whole thing.

Comment: This code is not calculating for the whole thing either. I suppose each key in tabular is already different. "Learning Center" is a key as far as I understand. Above code just adds the total after it is done with processing inner keys such as "1 meetings". Then it makes the total zero and process other key.

Comment: This is perfect, it calculated the total for each unique location. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell you what I understood from your question. For each end of the unique title, you need to display the total number of students. If that's your question then it is absolutely possible.

For that I would re-write the javascript as follows: 
***Please let me know if there is any small errors as I haven't debugged the code***

```
    function getTablularStats(resp) {
    console.log(resp);
    var tabular = resp.msg.tabular_num_meetings;
    var cohort = resp.msg.cohort;

    var uniqueKey = "";
    var numberOfStudents = 0;
    var flag = 0;

    var html = "";
    html += `<h5>Category: ${cohort}</h5>`;
    html += "<table class='table small table-responsible-sm table hover table-sm table-stripped'>";
    html += `<tr><th>Location</th><th>Meetings</th><th>Number of Students</th></tr>`;

    for (let key in tabular) {

        let obj = tabular[key]
        for (let innerKey in obj) {

            if (uniqueKey != key && flag != 0) {

                // Display the total students 
                html += '<tr><td colspan="2"> Total the number of students for that location :</td><td>' + numberOfStudents + '</td>';
                // Stores the new key 
                uniqueKey = key;
                // Reset the student counter
                numberOfStudents = 0;
                // Flag 0 is set so that the total doesn't show up for the first data from json
                flag = 1;

            }
            html += `<tr>`;
            html += `<td><b>${key}</b></td>`;
            html += `<td><b>${innerKey}</b></td>`;
            html += `<td><b>${obj[innerKey]}</b></td>`;
            html += `</tr>`;
            // Titles are stored so that can be checked for unique
            uniqueKey = key;
            // Sum is calculated on the go.
            numberOfStudents += obj[innerKey];
        }
    };
    html += "</table>";
    return html;
}
enter code here
```

Comment: I understand what this code is trying to do but for some reason it doesn't change anything in the output. There aren't any errors showing up either. You are correct in understanding the question though

Comment: When I console log the numberOfStudents in the innerloop, it seems to be totaling all the students as a whole. So I think there's something wrong with the if statement.

Comment: Can try debuggin the if and see where is it going wrong ?